# nginx как получить доступ к переменным одного модуля из другого?

Tags: c, nginx

Имеется 2 самописных модуля nginx, модуль вывода данных и модуль который содержит актуальные данные. Необходимо инициализировать указатель который находится в модуле вывода данных из модуля который содержит актуальные данные. Инициализировать этот указатель адресом на переменную с актуальными данными (которая периодически меняет свое значение), что бы в момент вывода данных, разыменовав указатель вывести актуальные данные.

Comment: Я не знаком с nginx, поэтому прошу уточнить :"модуль" - это что: задача / процесс / нитка / вызываемая функция ? В зависимости от этого и ответ будет разный.

Comment: Это большой фреймворк, и видимо для решения данной задачи нужно использовать какие то специфические функции данного фреймворка. Спасибо за интерес к данному вопросу.